# C - how does (*(void (*)()) code); run in a C program without any invocation

Tags: c, casting, hex, function-pointers, inline-assembly

To run arbitrary assembled hex instructions within a C program usually requires casting the data as a function pointer and then invoking such pointer.

**Common Usage**

```
int main(){    
    void (*ret)() = (void(*)())code;
    ret();
    return 0;
}
```

However I have also run across another way of achieving the same task as such

**Case in Question**

```
int main() {
    (*(void (*)()) code);
    return 0;
}
```

***Can someone help explain:***

1. The difference between the two cases
2. How come the second case works without any invocation

The problem arises when it is difficult to track the hex instruction code in a debugger such as GDB without an actual invocation of the hex code in script of the second case.

**Edit**

The program tested were compiled with gcc, and with options: `-fno-stack-protector -z exexcstack`

machine tested and gcc version :

```
gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)
```

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen is there a way to breakpoint at that moment of dereference in debug mode?

Comment: What version of gcc are you using? `(*(void (*)()) code);` should do nothing. Are you sure you have pasted the correct code?And are you sure the program actually ran as you expected? If you did run it and it did what was expected - are you sure you ran the right program?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes, the hex instructions executed as expected even in the second case.  I am using GCC 7.3.0

Comment: @MichaelPetch The hex instructions includes the syscall of opening a file for writing, and writing to it. After testing, the file exists and was written to. code was define as char code [] = "\xaa\xbb\xcc\xdd...";

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you a) actually compiled the right code b) ran the right program. Because as far as I'm concerned that one line shouldn't generate code that calls the function. If it had been `(*(void (*)()) code)()` instead of `(*(void (*)()) code);` then it should work.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Please ignore my foolishness as I had try to run the same program again and it failed. It seemed like I have ran the hexcode previously, which had the results left over. I apologize, the second case does nothing at all, without an invocation.

Comment: No problem. If that code worked I would have probably had to give up programming _C_ and take up basketweaving  ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second piece of code won't work.
The unused deref is a no-op. It's equivalent to an empty function.
If you want to avoid the variable use `((void (*)())code)()`.

Example:

```
extern char *code;
void run()
{
    void (*ret)() = (void(*)())code;
    ret();
}
void run0()
{
    (*(void (*)()) code);
}
void empty()
{
}
void novar()
{
    ((void (*)())code)();
}
```

Disassembly (x86_64) of Example:

```
ex.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <run>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
   8:   48 8b 05 00 00 00 00    mov    0x0(%rip),%rax        # f <run+0xf>
   f:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
  13:   48 8b 55 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdx
  17:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  1c:   ff d2                   callq  *%rdx
  1e:   90                      nop
  1f:   c9                      leaveq 
  20:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000021 <run0>:
  21:   55                      push   %rbp
  22:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  25:   90                      nop
  26:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  27:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000028 <empty>:
  28:   55                      push   %rbp
  29:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  2c:   90                      nop
  2d:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  2e:   c3                      retq   

000000000000002f <novar>:
  2f:   55                      push   %rbp
  30:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  33:   48 8b 05 00 00 00 00    mov    0x0(%rip),%rax        # 3a <novar+0xb>
  3a:   48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
  3d:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  42:   ff d2                   callq  *%rdx
  44:   90                      nop
  45:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  46:   c3                      retq
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/lEo5ga

Comment: Im sorry, I did not specify how the C code was compiled. It is with the options: -fno-stack-protector -z execstack using gcc. Will update the question now. And with those options, the hex instructions did execute

Comment: @Rennitbaby Those options don't make a difference. Linked a live example in Compiler Explorer.